# How to give Vanilla Items an NBT Tag for setting max durability ? Minecraft Forge [1.12.2]

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm still a bit of a beginner in Mc Modding and just learned how to use NBT Tags for my own Items,
and so my question is if it is possible to put an NBT Tag on existing Vanilla Items.

I'm trying to make a way too set the max durability(setMaxDamage) ingame for Tools, Weapon and Armor.
So I thought adding an NBT Tag "durability" for Any Item that Extends form ItemTool & ItemArmor.

How could I do that or is there an less difficult way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to add NBT tags to existing vanilla items. You can only add NBT tags to custom items that you have created yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can take away durability
lets say you wanted to give the player a diamond sword that has been used 500 times,
you would type /give player minecraft:diamond_sword{vanilla nbt if wanted} 1 500.
the last number is the amount of times it has been used